# Regex para esse formato xxxxxxxxxxxx_v2

Tags: regex

Como posso fazer um regex que aceita nesse formato a seguir:

```
1q2e5g6s4t5s2u1i5dy1s9u14i2s5u9o_v2
```

`1q2e5g6s4t5s2u1i5dy1s9u14i2s5u9o` tem 32 caracteres e depois tem `_v2` - os 3 últimos sempre são `_v2`.

Exemplos:

- `xxxxxxxxx_v2` - certo
- `a xxxxxxx_v2` - errado
- `sssssssss` - errado
- `ccccccc_v1` - errado
- `xxxxxxx_` - errado
- `kdkd ddd_v2` - errado

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As outras respostas sugeriram usar `\w`, que realmente aceita caracteres alfanuméricos (letras ou números), mas também aceita o caractere `_`.

Isso quer dizer que `^\w{32}_v2$` também considera válido uma string que tenha 32 caracteres `_` antes de `_v2` (ou seja, a string `_________________________________v2` seria considerada válida). Veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/3Ii3gB/1) esta regex funcionando.

Se é isso que você quer, tudo bem. Mas se quer limitar a somente 32 letras e números (e não aceitar nenhum outro `_` antes de `_v2`), mude a regex para `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}_v2$`. Veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/M42Xfo/1) a diferença.

---

Os colchetes (`[]`) representam uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Isso significa que qualquer caractere dentro deles serve. `[ab]`, por exemplo, significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b`" (qualquer uma delas serve).

No caso, eu coloquei dentro dos colchetes os atalhos `a-z` (qualquer letra de `a` a `z`), `A-Z` (qualquer letra de `A` a `Z`) e `0-9` (qualquer dígito de `0` a `9`). Ou seja, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` vai aceitar somente estes caracteres, enquanto `\w` aceita também o caractere `_` (o `\w` nada mais é que um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para `[A-Za-z0-9_]`).

---

**PS**: dependendo da linguagem/engine/configuração, `\w` pode ser ainda mais abrangente. Por exemplo, se a opção Unicode estiver habilitada, ele pode aceitar caracteres japoneses, árabes e muitos outros. (veja exemplos [aqui](https://ideone.com/ezq7NV) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/ZZxvvg/1/)).

Geralmente esta opção não vem habilitada por padrão, mas se quer garantir que somente letras do nosso alfabeto e dígitos de 0 a 9 sejam aceitos, use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

`\w` pode aceitar todos os casos que você precisa, mas também aceita outros que talvez você não precise (strings com `_` antes de `_v2`). Novamente, se isso não for um problema, então use `\w`. Mas se isso for um problema e você quiser evitar estes falsos positivos, [seja o mais específico possível](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) e use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

---

Não ficou muito claro se você quer "exatamente 32 caracteres" ou "de 1 a 32 caracteres" antes do `_v2`. De qualquer forma, basta mudar a regex de acordo com o que você precisa:

- exatamente 32 caracteres: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}_v2$`
- de 1 a 32 caracteres: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,32}_v2$`

Comment: +1 por não usar `\w` e erroneamente adicionar os `_` aos caracteres válidos.

Comment: @fernandosavio Pois é, esses atalhos (como `\w` e `\d`) são bem úteis, mas também escondem essas pequenas "armadilhas" (eu mesmo já caí em algumas...)

Answer (score 5):

Tente a seguinte expressão ([demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/brzqtZ/1)):

```
'/\w{32}_v2/'
```

Answer (score 5):

32 caracteres alfanuméricos são representados por `\w{32}`, _v2 é representado simplesmente por `_v2`, e para garantir que a sequencia tenha que começar e terminar com a regras que definimos (e não apenas possuir essa sequencia no meio), usamos `^` para sinalizar o começo, e `$` para sinalizar o fim, ou seja:

```
/^\w{32}_v2$/
```

Comment: Agora entendi, eu estava tentando fazer assim: `^\w[32]_v2$`